# LaTeXで\bibliographystyle{junsrt}を使うとエラーが出る

Tags: vscode, latex

LaTeXで`\bibliographystyle{junsrt}`を用いて参考文献を書こうとすると

```
Recipe terminated with error. Source:LaTeX Workshop(Extension)
```

と警告されて赤の×マークが表示されました。しかし、PROBLEMSの欄にはエラーの内容が何も指摘されていませんでした。またPDFは参考文献つきでしっかり生成されていました。どのようにしたらエラー表示が消えるのでしょうか。

以下が問題が発生するコード例になります。

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{ltjsarticle} 
\begin{document}
\section{はじめ}
\cite{key}
\bibliographystyle{junsrt}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

そして以下がtest.bibの中身です。

```
@misc{key,
  author       = {著者},
  howpublished = {},
  title        = {タイトル},
  year         = {2020}
}
```

アウトプットの中身も載せておきます。

```
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP932, CP932, CP932)
I changed them all to CP932
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 6 Nov. 2023. Version 4.81.
Latexmk: Doing main (small) clean up for 'c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex'
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Force everything to be remade.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'lualatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="out"  "c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-09>
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2022/09/12 ltjsclasses 
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-atbegshi.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jslogo.sty)) (./out/test.aux) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `key' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

No file test.bbl.
[1{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./out/test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

)
 797 words of node memory still in use:
   7 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 129 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 20 attribute_list, 1 write, 9 user_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:10,2:698,3:18,4:25,5:22,6:4,7:78,8:1,9:34,10:3
<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bold.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiGothic-Medium.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans12-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 7701 bytes).

SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Missing bbl file 'out/test.bbl' in following:
 No file test.bbl.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./test.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex out/test'...
Rule 'bibtex out/test':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'bibtex out/test' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex out/test'
------------
====== ENV{BIBINPUTS} changed to 'c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;out;C:\Users\81704\Documents\latex\out;'
Latexmk: Change directory to 'out/'.
To assist finding of files in document directory, I set
  BIBINPUTS='c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;out;C:\Users\81704\Documents\latex\out;'
  BSTINPUTS='c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;'.
------------
Running 'bibtex  "test.aux"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 228 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 244 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 257 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 266 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 307 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 312 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 397 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 407 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 427 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 433 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 450 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 504 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 515 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 547 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 558 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 560 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 580 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 587 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 637 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 646 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 657 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 672 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 682 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 687 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 711 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 716 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 736 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 763 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 777 of file junsrt.bst
Database file #1: test.bib
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1170 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1171 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1172 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1173 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1174 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1175 of file junsrt.bst
"タイトル" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"著者" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"著者" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1216 of file junsrt.bst
(There were 42 error messages)
Latexmk: Change directory back to 'c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex'
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  out/test.aux
  out/test.bbl

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="out"  "c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-09>
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2022/09/12 ltjsclasses 
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-atbegshi.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jslogo.sty)) (./out/test.aux) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `key' on page 1 undefined on input line 4.

(./out/test.bbl) [1{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./out/test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

)
 797 words of node memory still in use:
   7 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 129 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 20 attribute_list, 1 write, 9 user_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:12,2:1436,3:38,4:37,5:22,6:8,7:170,8:1,9:64,10:4
<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bold.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiGothic-Medium.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans12-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11674 bytes).

SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'out/test.bbl'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./test.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex out/test'...
Rule 'bibtex out/test':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  out/test.aux

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'bibtex out/test'
------------
====== ENV{BIBINPUTS} changed to 'c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;out;C:\Users\81704\Documents\latex\out;'
Latexmk: Change directory to 'out/'.
To assist finding of files in document directory, I set
  BIBINPUTS='c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;out;C:\Users\81704\Documents\latex\out;'
  BSTINPUTS='c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex;'.
------------
Running 'bibtex  "test.aux"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 228 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 244 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 257 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 266 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 307 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 312 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 397 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 407 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 427 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 433 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 450 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 504 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 515 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 547 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 558 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 560 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 580 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 587 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 637 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 646 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 657 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 672 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 682 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 687 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 711 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 716 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 736 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 763 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 777 of file junsrt.bst
Database file #1: test.bib
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1170 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1171 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1172 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1173 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1174 of file junsrt.bst
is.kanji.str$ is an unknown function---line 1175 of file junsrt.bst
"タイトル" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"著者" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1178 of file junsrt.bst
"著者" is a string literal, not an integer, for entry key
while executing---line 1216 of file junsrt.bst
(There were 42 error messages)
Latexmk: Change directory back to 'c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex'
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  out/test.aux

------------
Run number 3 of rule 'lualatex'
------------
------------
Running 'lualatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="out"  "c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex"'
------------
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-11-09>
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltjsarticle.cls
Document Class: ltjsarticle 2022/09/12 ltjsclasses 
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-atbegshi.sty) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.sty (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jslogo.sty)) (./out/test.aux) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (./out/test.bbl) [1{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./out/test.aux))
 797 words of node memory still in use:
   7 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 129 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 20 attribute_list, 1 write, 9 user_defined nodes
   avail lists: 1:12,2:1436,3:38,4:37,5:22,6:8,7:170,8:1,9:64,10:4
<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiGothic-Medium.otf><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans12-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10325 bytes).

SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'out/test.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'out/test.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./test.bib
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  bibtex out/test: Bibtex errors: See file 'out/test.blg'

C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -f -gg -lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error c:/Users/81704/Documents/latex/test -outdir=out
```

（追記）
文字数の都合で消しました。
（追記２）
settings.jsonの中身です。

```
{
    // 生成ファイルを "out" ディレクトリに吐き出す    
"latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "out",
    // 日本語文書で単語移動を使うため、助詞や読点、括弧を区切り文字として指定する
"editor.wordSeparators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?　、。「」【】『』（）！？てにをはがのともへでや",
//文章の折り畳み
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 120, //折り畳み位置

// 設定: LaTeX Workshop

// LaTeX Workshop ではビルド設定を「Tool」と「Recipe」という2つで考える
//   Tool: 実行される1つのコマンド。コマンド (command) と引数 (args) で構成される
//   Recipe: Tool の組み合わわせを定義する。Tool の組み合わせ (tools) で構成される。
//           tools の中で利用される Tool は "latex-workshop.latex.tools" で定義されている必要がある。

// latex-workshop.latex.tools: Tool の定義
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
  
    // latexmk を利用した lualatex によるビルドコマンド
    {
      "name": "Latexmk (LuaLaTeX)",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-f", "-gg", "-lualatex", "-synctex=1", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-file-line-error", "%DOC%", "-outdir=out"
      ]
    },
    // latexmk を利用した xelatex によるビルドコマンド
    {
      "name": "Latexmk (XeLaTeX)",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-f", "-gg", "-xelatex", "-synctex=1", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-file-line-error", "%DOC%", "-outdir=out"
      ]
    },
    // latexmk を利用した uplatex によるビルドコマンド
    {
      "name": "Latexmk (upLaTeX)",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-f", "-gg", "-synctex=1", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-file-line-error", "%DOC%", "-outdir=out"
      ]
    },
    // latexmk を利用した platex によるビルドコマンド
    // 古い LaTeX のテンプレートを使いまわしている (ドキュメントクラスが jreport や jsreport ) 場合のため
    {
      "name": "Latexmk (pLaTeX)",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-f", "-gg", "-latex='platex'", "-latexoption='-kanji=utf8 -no-guess-input-env'", "-synctex=1", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-file-line-error", "%DOC%", "-outdir=out"
      ]
    }
],

// latex-workshop.latex.recipes: Recipe の定義
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    // LuaLaTeX で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
    {
      "name": "LuaLaTeX",
      "tools": [
        "Latexmk (LuaLaTeX)"
      ]
    },
    // XeLaTeX で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
    {
      
      "name": "XeLaTeX",
      "tools": [
        "Latexmk (XeLaTeX)"
      ]
    },
    // LaTeX(upLaTeX) で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
    {
      "name": "upLaTeX",
      "tools": [
        "Latexmk (upLaTeX)"
      ]
    },
    // LaTeX(pLaTeX) で書かれた文書のビルドレシピ
    {
      "name": "pLaTeX",
      "tools": [
        "Latexmk (pLaTeX)"
      ]
    },
],

// latex-workshop.latex.magic.args: マジックコメント付きの LaTeX ドキュメントをビルドする設定
// '%!TEX' で始まる行はマジックコメントと呼ばれ、LaTeX のビルド時にビルドプログラムに解釈され、
// プログラムの挙動を制御する事ができる。
// 参考リンク: https://blog.miz-ar.info/2016/11/magic-comments-in-tex/
"latex-workshop.latex.magic.args": [
  "-f", "-gg", "-pv", "-synctex=1", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "-file-line-error", "%DOC%"
],

// latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes: クリーンアップ時に削除されるファイルの拡張子
// LaTeX 文書はビルド時に一時ファイルとしていくつかのファイルを生成するが、最終的に必要となるのは
// PDF ファイルのみである場合などが多い。また、LaTeX のビルド時に失敗した場合、失敗時に生成された
// 一時ファイルの影響で、修正後のビルドに失敗してしまう事がよくある。そのため、一時的なファイルを
// 削除する機能 (クリーンアップ) が LaTeX Workshop には備わっている。
// (注意：".toc"が削除されると目次が生成されず，"*.synctex.gz"が削除されると，synctex が効かなくなります。）
"latex-workshop.latex.clean.fileTypes": [
  "*.aux", "*.bbl","*.idx", "*.ind", "*.lof", "*.lot", "*.out", "*.acn", "*.acr", "*.alg", "*.glg", "*.glo", "*.gls", "*.ist", "*.fls", "*.log", "*.fdb_latexmk",
    // for Beamer files
    "_minted*", "*.nav", "*.snm", "*.vrb",
],

// latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run: ビルド失敗時に一時ファイルのクリーンアップを行うかどうか
// 上記説明にもあったように、ビルド失敗時に生成された一時ファイルが悪影響を及ぼす事があるため、自動で
// クリーンアップがかかるようにしておく。

"latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt",

// PDFとlatexの文を飛ぶ
"latex-workshop.synctex.synctexjs.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.synctex.afterBuild.enabled": true,

// latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run: .tex ファイルの保存時に自動的にビルドを行うかどうか（neverにするとしなくなる,onFileChangeに変えた）
// LaTeX ファイルは .tex ファイルを変更後にビルドしないと、PDF ファイル上に変更結果が反映されないため、
// .tex ファイルの保存と同時に自動的にビルドを実行する設定があるが、文書が大きくなるに連れてビルドにも
// 時間がかかってしまい、ビルドプログラムの負荷がエディタに影響するため、neverで無効化しておく。
"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onFileChange", 

"[tex]": {
    // スニペット補完中にも補完を使えるようにする
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    // インデント幅を2にする
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},

"[latex]": {
    // スニペット補完中にも補完を使えるようにする
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    // インデント幅を2にする
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},

"[bibtex]": {
    // インデント幅を2にする
    "editor.tabSize": 2
},
"latex-workshop.latex.clean.method": "glob",
"latex-workshop.latex.clean.subfolder.enabled": true,
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.zoom": "page-width",
"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.internal.synctex.keybinding": "double-click",
"japanese-proofreading.textlint.ピリオドとカンマの使用（全角）": false,
"japanese-proofreading.textlint.ピリオドとカンマの使用（半角）": false,

"todo-tree.regex.regex": "((//|#|%|<!--|;|/\\*|^)\\s*($TAGS)|^\\s*- \\[ \\])",
"japanese-proofreading.textlint.算用数字と漢数字の使い分け": false,
"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false, //TODO treeへlatexのコメントアウト%を対応させる

}
```

Comment: BibTeXでエラーが起きていそうですね。`bibtex out/test: Bibtex errors: See file 'out/test.blg'`とあるので、ファイル`out/test.blg`があればその中身も追加してください。また普通のBibTeXは日本語に対応していないので、それが原因な気もします（日本語の場合は`pbibtex`を使用します）。`test.bib`の中身を英語のみにするとうまくいきませんか？

Comment: test.bibを英語だけにしてもうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: やはりpbibtexではなくbibtexを使用しているのが原因で間違いなさそうです。英語のみにしても`junsrt.bst`がpbibtexを前提にしているのでエラーになるわけですね。

Comment: LaTeX Workshop というのは Visual Studio Codeの 拡張のようですね。間違い無ければ、その点を質問に追記していただくと、解り易いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ログ内に以下の行があるのでBibTeXを使用していますね。

```
Running 'bibtex  "test.aux"'
```

bibtexコマンドは日本語に対応していないので、代わりにpbibtexコマンドを使用します。

LaTeX Workshopでbibtexの代わりにpbibtexを使う方法は色々あります。これに関しては好みの問題もあるので、できればインターネット上で情報収集してお好みの方法を決めてください。

---

以下では、追記していただいたLaTeX Workshopの設定（`setting.json`）と下記の記事を参考にした上で一例を示します：

- [なるべくデフォルトのまま使いたい人へ #LaTeXWorkshop - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Yarakashi_Kikohshi/items/e9270af54569640fe80f)

私はLaTeX Workshopユーザではないので動作確認等はしていませんが、きちんと設定しないとlatexmkrcの内容がビルド時に反映されないのかもしれません。

まず現在の`setting.json`内の`latex-workshop.latex.tools`と`latex-workshop.latex.recipes`の中身がかなりごちゃごちゃしていてよくわからないことになっているので、これらの設定を行っている部分は全部消去してデフォルト設定に戻します。

その上で、`setting.json`に以下を追記します。

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
```

これでlatexmkrcの内容がビルドに反映されるようになるはずです。その上で、pbibtexを使用するようにlatexmkrcを作成します。以下は最低限の設定をした例です。

```perl
$lualatex = 'lualatex %O -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %S';
$pdflualatex = $lualatex;
$bibtex = 'pbibtex %O %B';
$pdf_mode = 4;
```

latexmkrcの設定方法の詳細も、インターネット上にたくさん情報があるので、詳しくは外部の情報を調べてみてください。

Comment: 上記のコマンドをlatexmkrcに入力してみたのですが、変わらずbibtexを使ってビルドしているようでうまくいきません。

Comment: LaTeX Workshopのレシピ設定（`setting.json`？）を載せてもらわないと状況がよくわかりませんが、latexmkrcを使わない設定になっているのですかね？ レシピで直接pbibtexを使うように設定する方法もあると思います。

Comment: 前の時点でupbibtexになっていたのでその可能性がある気がします。settings.jsonの中身も追加しました。

Comment: いちおうLaTeX Workshopの設定方法も追記してみました。これは方法が一通りではなく色々あるところです（好みもあります）。私はLaTeX Workshopを使用していないので、本当にこれでよいかはちょっとわかりません。